# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class (Category,SubCategory,Product)

Tags: java, jpa

I devised Category,SubCategory and Product entities for JSF project and I had an issue about mapping between SubCategory and Product with ManytoMany relation. Here are Category,SubCategory and Products below. How can I solve out this mapping excepiton. Thks.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="CATEGORY",schema="DEMO")
    public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="catseq",sequenceName="seqCatSEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="catseq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="CAT_DESC")
    private String catDesc;


    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST },mappedBy="category")
    private Set<SubCategory> subcategories = new HashSet();

    public Category() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Category(String name, String catDesc) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.catDesc = catDesc;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCatDesc() {
        return catDesc;
    }

    public void setCatDesc(String catDesc) {
        this.catDesc = catDesc;
    }


    public Set<SubCategory> getSubcategories() {
        return subcategories;
    }


    public void setSubcategories(Set<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }


}
```

SubCategory:

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="SUBCATEGORY",schema="DEMO")
public class SubCategory implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="subcatseq",sequenceName="seqSubCatSEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="subcatseq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="SUBNAME")
    private String SubName;

    @Column(name="SUBNAME_DESC")
    private String SubNameDes;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy="subcategories")
    Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();


    public SubCategory() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SubCategory(String subName, String subNameDes) {
        super();
        SubName = subName;
        SubNameDes = subNameDes;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubName() {
        return SubName;
    }

    public void setSubName(String subName) {
        SubName = subName;
    }

    public String getSubNameDes() {
        return SubNameDes;
    }

    public void setSubNameDes(String subNameDes) {
        SubNameDes = subNameDes;
    }


    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }



}
```

Product:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS",schema="DEMO")
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="proseq",sequenceName="proSEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="proseq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private Double price;

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_DESC")
    private String productDes;


    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY", 
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SUBCATEGORY_ID")}
    ) 
    Set<SubCategory> subcategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();


    public Product() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public Product(String productName, Integer quantity, Double price, String productDes,
            Set<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.productDes = productDes;
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }


    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }


    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }


    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public String getProductDes() {
        return productDes;
    }


    public void setProductDes(String productDes) {
        this.productDes = productDes;
    }


    public Set<SubCategory> getSubcategories() {
        return subcategories;
    }


    public void setSubcategories(Set<SubCategory> subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }


}
```

Comment: is your `component-scan` set to the correct packages? Is the package Statement missing in the copied code or are the entities in different packages?

Comment: For many to many relation, I would like remove `CascadeType` setttings in the `@ManyToMany` annotation. 1. persist Subcategory, 2. persist product. 3. set the relations between subcategories and product and sync session change into database(if this step are not in the same Session of 1 and 2, you could have to merge the state of SubCategory and Product manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `mappedby` is defined as It refers to the field who owns the relationship, By other meaning mapped by refers to the table class which has the foreign key

So we have two `mappedBy` that are suspiecous lets take them one by one :

1-

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST },mappedBy="category")
    private Set<SubCategory> subcategories = new HashSet();
```

That means that `subcategory` table and class owns the relationship field so `subcategory` table is the one who have the foreign key and from `SubCategory` class the foreign key name is `CAT_ID` so this one is OK.

2-

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy="subcategories")
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
```

Ok this one shows that there is a field called `subcategories` in `Product` class this one owns the relationship **BAM** this is not true since this is `ManyToMany` the owner of the relationship should be a third table exists on database and have to be logically understood by hibernate

So this is the issue `mappedBy` refers to the the field which is not the owner of the relationship and since the owner is some anonymous entity
this have to be like this :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY", 
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SUBCATEGORY_ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")}
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
```

- Note Your `PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY` table should only have two primary keys and should be primary so that hibernate understands that this is `ManyToMany` relationship